# How are implicit intents used with the Jetpack Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

The Jetpack Navigation Component docs say that activities can be set as destinations, but they don't say anything about using implicit intents as destinations. Is this possible, and if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Navigation Deep Linking documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Deeplink), you can associate a URI with a destination by using a `<deepLink>` element in your navigation graph:

```
<deepLink app:uri="www.example.com/topics/{topicName}"/>
```

This is the only kind of implicit Intent that is available with the Navigation Architecture Component at this time.